# com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException from Soap Web service

Tags: java, data-binding, jaxb

I have trouble accessing data from my webservice.It gives the error below when run.I have a class that contains a
gson reader which fetches the urls from the web service.There is an error fetching the urls which yields the following exception.

```
Error getting URLs com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 17 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://tempuri.org/}emailAddress.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement org.tempuri.GetPractitionerSystem.emailAddress
        at org.tempuri.GetPractitionerSystem
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://tempuri.org/}password.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement org.tempuri.GetPractitionerSystem.password
        at org.tempuri.GetPractitionerSystem
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://tempuri.org/}clientJSON.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement org.tempuri.AddClient.clientJSON
        at org.tempuri.AddClient
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://tempuri.org/}emailAddress.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement org.tempuri.AddClient.emailAddress
        at org.tempuri.AddClient
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://tempuri.org/}password.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement org.tempuri.AddClient.password
        at org.tempuri.AddClient
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://tempuri.org/}AddClientResult.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement org.tempuri.AddClientResponse.addClientResult
        at org.tempuri.AddClientResponse
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://tempuri.org/}GetURLsResult.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement org.tempuri.GetURLsResponse.getURLsResult
        at org.tempuri.GetURLsResponse.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that all I had to do was declare an XmlElementRef tag containing the name,namespace and type on top of each JAXBElement variable declaration and add an @XmlDecl tag on top of each setter method in my ObjectFactory class that I wanted to retrieve as a JAXBElement ,and finally add a getter method.For instance, if I wanted to get studentName, all I had to do is declare elements in my OjectFactory class as below:

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "GetStudentName", namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> getStudentName;
```

then on top of the method, i'll do:

```
   @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", name = "GetStudentName")
    public JAXBElement<String> getGetStudentName() {
        return getStudentName;
    }

 public void setGetStudentName(JAXBElement<String> value) {
        this.getStudentName = value;
    }
```